# Can this loop in a numba function be optimized to run faster?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, loops, numba

In my `python` code, I need to loop over about 25 million times, which I want to optimize as much as possible. The operations within the loop are very simple. In order to make the code efficient, I have used `numba` module, which helps tremendously, but if possible I would like to further optimize the code.

Here is a complete working example:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import time 
#######create some synthetic data for illustration purpose##################
size=5000
eps = 0.2
theta_c = 0.4
temp = np.ones(size)
neighbour = np.random.randint(size, size=(size, 3)) 
coschi = np.random.random_sample((size))
theta = np.random.random_sample((size))*np.pi/2
pwr = np.cos(theta)
###################end of dummy data##########################

###################-----main loop------###############
@nb.jit(fastmath=True)
def func(theta, pwr, neighbour, coschi, temp):
    for k in range(np.argmax(pwr), 5000*(pwr.size)): 
        n = k%pwr.size
        if (np.abs(theta[n]-np.pi/2.)<np.abs(theta_c)):
                adj = neighbour[n,1]
        else:
                adj = neighbour[n,0]
        psi_diff = np.abs(np.arccos(coschi[adj])-np.arccos(coschi[n]))
        temp5 = temp[adj]**5;
        e_temp = 1.- np.exp(-temp5*psi_diff/np.abs(eps))
        temp[n] = temp[adj] + (e_temp)/temp5*(pwr[n] - temp[adj]**4)
    return temp

#check time
time1 = time.time()
temp = func(theta, pwr, neighbour, coschi, temp)
print("Took: ", time.time()-time1, " seconds.")
```

This takes `3.49 seconds` on my machine.

I need to run this code several thousand time for some model fitting purpose, and therefore the optimization of even 1 second means saving tens of hours for me.

What can be done to further optimize this code?

Comment: On my machine, the assignment to temp[n] takes about 75% of the time. If I delete the assignment before return temp, the runtime is ~0.55 seconds. If you can find a better data structure for temp, you may be able to improve this.

Comment: Apart from other answers so far 1) Make sure you have Intel SVML installed (significant speedup of functions like cos, arccos,...). http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html 2)You can also set error_model="numpy" to avoid the costly division by zero checking. 3)You are measuring a mixture of compilation and runtime, run the function once before timing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me begin with some general comments:

- If you use numba and really care about performance you should avoid any possibility that numba creates object-mode code. That means you should use `numba.njit(...)` or `numba.jit(nopython=True, ...)` instead of `numba.jit(...)`.

  That doesn't make a difference in your case but it makes the intent clearer and throws exceptions as soon as something isn't supported in (the fast) nopython mode.
- You should be careful what you time and how. The first call to a numba-jitted function (that is not compiled ahead-of-time) will include the compilation cost. So you need to run it once before you time it to get accurate timings. And for more accurate timings you should call the function more than once. I like IPythons `%timeit` in Jupyter Notebooks/Lab to get some rough idea about performance.

  So I will use:

  ```
  res1 = func(theta, pwr, neighbour, coschi, np.ones(size))
  res2 = # other approach

  np.testing.assert_allclose(res1, res2)

  %timeit func(theta, pwr, neighbour, coschi, np.ones(size))
  %timeit # other approach
  ```

  That way I use the first call (which includes the compilation time) with an assert to make sure it really produces (almost) the same output and then time the function using a more robust timing method (compared to `time`).

### Hoisting `np.arccos`

Now let's start with some actual performance optimizations: One obvious one is that you can hoist some "invariants", for example the `np.arccos(coschi[...])` is calculated much more often than there are actual elements in the `coschi`. You iterate over each element in `coschi` roughly 5000 times and it's doing two `np.arccos` per loop! So let's calculate the `arccos` of the `coschi` once and store it in an intermediate array so one can access that inside the loop:

```py
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def func2(theta, pwr, neighbour, coschi, temp):
    arccos_coschi = np.arccos(coschi)
    for k in range(np.argmax(pwr), 5000 * pwr.size): 
        n = k % pwr.size
        if np.abs(theta[n] - np.pi / 2.) < np.abs(theta_c):
            adj = neighbour[n, 1]
        else:
            adj = neighbour[n, 0]
        psi_diff = np.abs(arccos_coschi[adj] - arccos_coschi[n])
        temp5 = temp[adj]**5;
        e_temp = 1. - np.exp(-temp5 * psi_diff / np.abs(eps))
        temp[n] = temp[adj] + e_temp / temp5 * (pwr[n] - temp[adj]**4)
    return temp
```

On my computer that's significantly faster already:

```
1.73 s ± 54.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)  # original
811 ms ± 49.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)  # func2
```

However it comes at a price: The results will be different! I consistently get significantly different results using the original and the hoisted version with `fastmath=True`. However the results are (almost) equal with `fastmath=False`. It seems that `fastmath` enables some rigorous optimizations with `np.arccos(coschi[adj]) - np.arccos(coschi[n])` that are not possible when the `np.arccos` is hoisted. In my personal opinion I would neglect the `fastmath=True` if you care about exact results or you have tested that the accuracy of the results isn't significantly affected by fastmath!

### Hoisting `adj`

The next thing to hoist would be the `adj`, it's also calculated much more often than necessary:

```py
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def func3(theta, pwr, neighbour, coschi, temp):
    arccos_coschi = np.arccos(coschi)
    associated_neighbour = np.empty(neighbour.shape[0], nb.int64)
    for idx in range(neighbour.shape[0]):
        if np.abs(theta[idx] - np.pi / 2.) < np.abs(theta_c):
            associated_neighbour[idx] = neighbour[idx, 1]
        else:
            associated_neighbour[idx] = neighbour[idx, 0]

    for k in range(np.argmax(pwr), 5000 * pwr.size): 
        n = k % pwr.size
        adj = associated_neighbour[n]
        psi_diff = np.abs(arccos_coschi[adj] - arccos_coschi[n])
        temp5 = temp[adj]**5;
        e_temp = 1. - np.exp(-temp5 * psi_diff / np.abs(eps))
        temp[n] = temp[adj] + e_temp / temp5 * (pwr[n] - temp[adj]**4)
    return temp
```

The effect of this isn't that big, but measurable:

```
1.75 s ± 110 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)  # original
761 ms ± 28.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) # func2
660 ms ± 8.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) # func3
```

Hoisting additional calculations seemed to have no effect on the performance on my computer so I don't include them here. So it seems that's how far you can get without changing the algorithm.

### Refactored into smaller functions (+ small additional changes)

However I would recommend to separate the hoisting in other functions and make all variables function parameters instead of looking up the globals. That probably won't result in speed-ups but it could make the code more readable:

```py
@nb.njit
def func4_inner(indices, pwr, associated_neighbour, arccos_coschi, temp, abs_eps):
    for n in indices:
        adj = associated_neighbour[n]
        psi_diff = np.abs(arccos_coschi[adj] - arccos_coschi[n])
        temp5 = temp[adj]**5;
        e_temp = 1. - np.exp(-temp5 * psi_diff / abs_eps)
        temp[n] = temp[adj] + e_temp / temp5 * (pwr[n] - temp[adj]**4)
    return temp

@nb.njit
def get_relevant_neighbor(neighbour, abs_theta_minus_pi_half, abs_theta_c):
    associated_neighbour = np.empty(neighbour.shape[0], nb.int64)
    for idx in range(neighbour.shape[0]):
        if abs_theta_minus_pi_half[idx] < abs_theta_c:
            associated_neighbour[idx] = neighbour[idx, 1]
        else:
            associated_neighbour[idx] = neighbour[idx, 0]
    return associated_neighbour

def func4(theta, pwr, neighbour, coschi, temp, theta_c, eps):
    arccos_coschi = np.arccos(coschi)
    abs_theta_minus_pi_half = np.abs(theta - (np.pi / 2.))
    relevant_neighbors = get_relevant_neighbor(neighbour, abs_theta_minus_pi_half, abs(theta_c))
    argmax_pwr = np.argmax(pwr)
    indices = np.tile(np.arange(pwr.size), 5000)[argmax_pwr:]
    return func4_inner(indices, pwr, relevant_neighbors, arccos_coschi, temp, abs(eps))
```

Here I also did some additional changes:

- calculated the indices beforehand using `np.tile` and slicing instead of the `range` approach together with `%`.
- Used plain NumPy (outside of numba) to calculate the `np.arccos`.

### Final timings and summary

```
1.79 s ± 49.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)  # original
844 ms ± 41.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)  # func2
707 ms ± 31.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)  # func3
550 ms ± 4.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)  # func4
```

So in the end the latest approach is roughly 3 times faster (without `fastmath`) than the original approach. If you're sure that you want to use `fastmath`, then just apply `fastmath=True` on the `func4_inner` and it will be even faster:

```
499 ms ± 4.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)  # func4 with fastmath on func4_inner
```

However as I have already stated `fastmath` may not be appropriate if you want exact (or at least not too inexact) results.

Also several optimizations here depend a lot on the available hardware and processor caches (especially for memory-bandwidth-limited portions of the code). You have to check how these approaches perform relative to each other on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Numba is really great. But you are desperate, remember you can always [write in C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4YRPdRXKFs) (youtube). On my own problem I got a 30% performance gain over numba just by translating line by line to C.

If you want to spend that effort, I suggest to use [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) for vector operations (with vector size know at compile-time) and [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/) because it translates natively between numpy and eigen. Keep your main loop in Python, of course. Make sure you use the appropriate compiler flags (like `-O3` `-march=native`, `-mtune=native`, `-ffast-math`) and try different compilers (for me `gcc` output was 2x faster than `clang`, but colleagues have reported the opposite).

If you don't know any C++ it may be smarter to limit yourself to pure C and no libraries (because it reduces complexity). But you'll deal with the Python and numpy C API directly (not that hard, but a lot more code, and you'll learn all about Python internals).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be processing a lot of duplicates in your example.

In this version, I'm not recalculating any value for an 'n' that we've already seen.

I don't know if this is ok in your case or not, but it saves ~0.4 seconds for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import time
#######create some synthetic data for illustration purpose##################
size = 5000
eps = 0.2
theta_c = 0.4
temp = np.ones(size)
neighbour = np.random.randint(size, size=(size, 3))
coschi = np.random.random_sample((size))
theta = np.random.random_sample((size))*np.pi/2
pwr = np.cos(theta)
###################end of dummy data##########################

###################-----main loop------###############
@nb.jit(fastmath=True)
def func(theta, pwr, neighbour, coschi, temp):

    hashtable = {}

    for k in range(np.argmax(pwr), 5000*(pwr.size)):
        n = k % pwr.size

        if not hashtable.get(n, False):
            hashtable[n] = 1

            #taking into account regions with different super wind direction
            if (np.abs(theta[n]-np.pi/2.) < np.abs(theta_c)):
                    adj = neighbour[n, 1]
            else:
                    adj = neighbour[n, 0]
            psi_diff = np.abs(np.arccos(coschi[adj])-np.arccos(coschi[n]))
            temp5 = temp[adj]**5
            e_temp = 1. - np.exp(-temp5*psi_diff/np.abs(eps))
            retval = temp[adj] + (e_temp)/temp5*(pwr[n] - temp[adj]**4)

            temp[n] = retval


    return temp


#check time
time1 = time.time()
result = func(theta, pwr, neighbour, coschi, temp)
print("Took: ", time.time()-time1, "
```

Original : Hashtable

2.3726098537445070 : 1.8722639083862305

2.3447792530059814 : 1.9053585529327393

2.3363733291625977 : 1.9104151725769043

2.3447978496551514 : 1.9298338890075684

2.4740016460418700 : 1.9088914394378662

**A bare bones loop of 25M items using np.ones:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import time

temp = np.ones(25000000)

@nb.jit(fastmath=True)
def func(temp):
    return [n for n in temp]

time1 = time.time()
result = func(temp)
print("Took: ", time.time()-time1, " seconds for ", len(temp), " items")
```

Took:  1.2502222061157227  seconds for 25000000  items

Took:  1.294729232788086  seconds for 25000000  items

Took:  1.2670648097991943  seconds for 25000000  items

Took:  1.2386720180511475  seconds for 25000000  items

Took:  1.2517566680908203  seconds for 25000000  items

Comment: I just had another idea. If this problem can be split (and it seems like it may be possible), you may be able to use threads and/or concurrency to calculate subsets of the space simultaneously and recombine them at the end. I don't have time to try it now, but it will be an interesting exercise.

Comment: I think the repeated calculation of the `temp[n]` values is intended, otherwise it wouldn't make sense to loop until `5000 * pwr.size`, one could stop much (much) earlier, at `pwr.size + np.argmax(pwr)` to be precise. This multiple cross-computation also makes the problem very hard to parallelize since one has to calculate subsets of indices that may affect each other and don't compute these in parallel.

Comment: Admittedly, I don't fully understand what this fumction does, ut since we are sometimes overwriting temp[n] before ever using it again, it seems likw wasted effort. The problem space may be too large, but even something like rainbow tables might help here.

Comment: I assume it's an iterative fitting function so it makes sense to override the `temp[n]` depending on the iteration-count. I also don't understand the algorithm (or reasoning behind it) but the approach in your answer significantly changes the output. I just wanted to make you aware of that - in case you didn't noticed.

Comment: This was supposed to be an iterative method as @MSeifert pointed out.